# Windows 10 system slowing down massively

Tags: windows

I am facing a problem that bothers me very much the last few weeks.
My Windows 10 system is slowing down massively after a few days.

I rarely shut down my system so my PC is running 24/7 which is totally fine, but after ~48h it slows that much down I cannot even watch videos on YouTube without juddering. Even VLC does not play the files smoothly it comes to a point where I cannot even hear the sound properly. And the cursor also does not flow smoothly as I am used to, it looks more like a dia show when my system suddenly stops and hangs all the time.

My system is pretty good:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tiq6.png]

I checked task manager but cannot find a task which consumes too much CPU or RAM. It seems quite normal:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8cHW.png]

Sure Chrome is consuming RAM like hell but even if I close Chrome my system does not run smooth again.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/obmqV.png]

I am just not able to find the problem and fix it.
The ONLY option is to restart my system, then everything is fine for abour 48h and then it begins to hang again. I am sick of restarting it again and again just to watch a YouTube video :|

CPU Temp is as usual and not suspicious

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/orXVR.png]

Ressource Monitor Screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiRUd.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv9pk.png]

I am using a water cooled system and an SSD for my Windows OS, HDD for my files and stuff if it makes a difference. And tips or suggestions? Besides virus check and reformatting the system? 
It makes working on my PC a pain in the a...

Comment: you have a lot of handles. Maybe you also have too many [Zombie Processes](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2018/02/11/zombie-processes-are-eating-your-memory/). So activate the Handle column in Taskmgr and look if a process has a lot of those handles.